# TYPO3 gridelements: Render image from FlexForm FAL field

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm trying to render multiple FCE (gridelements content elements) of the same type. However, images are not rendered.

The flexform defining that FCE has an image field exactly like this:

```
<image>
    <TCEforms>
        <config>
            <type>inline</type>
            <appearance type="array">
                <createNewRelationLinkTitle>LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:createNewRelationLinkTitle</createNewRelationLinkTitle>
                <headerThumbnail type="array">
                    <field>uid_local</field>
                    <height>45c</height>
                    <width>45</width>
                </headerThumbnail>
            </appearance>
            <foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>
            <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
            <foreign_match_fields type="array">
                <fieldname>image</fieldname>
            </foreign_match_fields>
            <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
            <foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride type="array">
                <config type="array">
                    <appearance type="array">
                        <elementBrowserAllowed>gif,jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,bmp,pcx,tga,png,pdf,ai</elementBrowserAllowed>
                        <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                    </appearance>
                </config>
            </foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
            <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
            <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>
            <foreign_table_field>tablenames</foreign_table_field>
            <maxitems>1</maxitems>
            <minitems>0</minitems>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</image>
```

The TypoScript defining the element looks this way:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
  3 < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
  3 {
    stdWrap.cObject = COA
    stdWrap.cObject {
      10 = IMAGE
      10 {
        stdWrap.wrap = <div class="media-left">|</div>
        file {
          import.data = field:flexform_image
          treatIdAsReference = 1
          import.listNum = 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**The issue**
When putting on element onto a page, the image is displayed. Putting multiple elements on the same page leads to each element rendering the image from the first FCE put onto the page. As soon as I edit an FCE (e.g. the second placed element), no images are displayed at all.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be sure that filename is unique for every flexform field:

```
<foreign_match_fields type="array">
    <fieldname>image</fieldname>
</foreign_match_fields>
```

Best is to use the real field name. For example flexform_image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the flexform

```
<T3DataStructure>
    <meta>
        <langDisable>1</langDisable>
    </meta>
    <ROOT type="array">
        <type>array</type>
        <el type="array">
        <bgimage>
            <TCEforms>
        <label>Background Image</label>
                <config>
                    <type>inline</type>

                    <foreign_field>uid_foreign</foreign_field>
                    <foreign_label>uid_local</foreign_label>
                    <foreign_match_fields type="array">
                        <fieldname>bgimage</fieldname>
                    </foreign_match_fields>
                    <foreign_selector>uid_local</foreign_selector>
                    <foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride type="array">
                        <config type="array">
                            <appearance type="array">
                                <elementBrowserAllowed>gif,jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,bmp,pcx,tga,png,pdf,ai</elementBrowserAllowed>
                                <elementBrowserType>file</elementBrowserType>
                            </appearance>
                        </config>
                    </foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride>
                    <foreign_sortby>sorting_foreign</foreign_sortby>
                    <foreign_table>sys_file_reference</foreign_table>

                    <maxitems>1</maxitems>
                    <minitems>0</minitems>
                </config>
            </TCEforms>
        </bgimage>
        </el>
    </ROOT>
</T3DataStructure>
```